# Json response not being printed

Tags: java, android, json, apache, http

I am new to Android and Java development. I would highly appreciate if someone could guide me:

My code:

```
public class TokenPost extends MainActivity {

public TokenPost(MainActivity mainActivity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void postData() {

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                try{
                    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.traxbuddy.com/confirm.json");

                    Log.i("Inside TokenPost", "Inside TokenPost");
                        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
                        //String foo= "id_token="+token+"&lat="+59.8944400+"&lng="+30.2641700;
                        //nameValuePair1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_token", token ));
                          Log.i("Mobile Token", "Mobile Token" + mtokenno);
                          nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile", "919876543285"));
                          nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("imei", "911212345123891"/*imeicontact*/));
                          nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stoken", mtokenno));

                        // Execute HTTP Post Request



                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        Log.i("Response from Http Post Request", "Response from Http Post Request: "+ response);

                        System.out.println("Response: " +response.toString());

                        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
                        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
                        JsonElement je = jp.parse(response.toString());
                        String prettyJsonString = gson.toJson(je);
                        System.out.println(je);
                        System.out.println(prettyJsonString);

                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
                        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                       for (line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
                           builder.append(line).append("\n");

                           System.out.println(line); }

                    }
                    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start(); 


}//postData 
}
```

The output that I am getting in the log is:

```
10-07 13:28:49.803: I/Inside TokenPost(1312): Inside TokenPost
10-07 13:28:49.803: I/Mobile Token(1312): Mobile Tokennull
10-07 13:29:02.573: I/Response from Http Post Request(1312): Response from Http Post Request:    org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@b20e3f18
10-07 13:29:02.573: I/System.out(1312): Response:  org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@b20e3f18
10-07 13:29:02.603: I/System.out(1312): "org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@b20e3f18"
10-07 13:29:02.603: I/System.out(1312): "org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@b20e3f18"
10-07 13:29:02.603: W/System.err(1312): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-07 13:29:02.613: W/System.err(1312): at com.traxbuddy.trax.TokenPost$1.run(TokenPost.java:68)
10-07 13:29:02.613: W/System.err(1312): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

The output that I should have got(I got it by using CURL):

```
{"atoken":"11528aa467271341a624f362ee7dd268b0366016","utoken":"c6205d52218f6d466
e2c4bac3ecc585ddab9db96"}
```

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that `response.getEntity().getContent()` returns `null`, triggering the NPE.

Have you tried deserializing the body using this:

```
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
// ...
String json = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I tried the above changes, but got the following exception:

10-07 15:18:09.183: W/System.err(1558): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HTTP entity may not be null

10-07 15:18:09.193: W/System.err(1558):  at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(EntityUtils.java:110)

Comment: immediately after the execute, can you add `Log.e("resp.length", ""+response.getEntity().getContentLength());` - what does this show.

Comment: It returns: W/System.err(2274): java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to parse `response.toString()`, which is `"org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@b20e3f18"`,  as a JsonElement, triggering exception.

replace

```
    JsonElement je = jp.parse(response.toString());
```

with

```
    JsonElement je = jp.parse(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I tried with above changes, but, got the following exception:
1.  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HTTP entity may not be null at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(EntityUtils.java:110)

Comment: you are doing a `HttpPost` its response could be `null`, may be `GET` after the post ?

Comment: I just tried making the POST request using "POSTMAN - REST Client" and got the perfect response as:

{"atoken":"e951cc75c1738409f0fa13f0e8e73fc616e5ded2","utoken":"b1f4b870d7723e1d8
144901b989daab033629fe8"}. 

This implies that the response is not null. Probably something is wrong within my code.